# Finding out if Input text is for corona virus or not

Tags: python, model, nlp, classification, text-classification

Hope everyone is doing well. I am new to nlp and I am trying to write a program that can tell me if the user's input is meant to talk one of my three models chatbots

- **covid-casual chatbot** (A model trained on non-medical twitter data)
- **covid-medical chatbot** (data from patient's visit to the doctor's office)
- **casual conversation chatbot** (my last model is a casual agent)

What would be the most reliable way to analyze the user's input to choose between the 3 categories?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this through a supervised machine learning model. You need to train your model so it will know what category to assign in each prediction

Comment: Yeah I was thinking of using a Word2Vec gensim model using some Corona Virus tweets. Was just thinking what other models would produce more accurate results? Thanks for your reply!